# Intel Graphics Installer for Linux ends with an error in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, software-installation

Everytime I try to install the Intel Graphics Installer for Linux it always end up with this 2 screens looking like this.

[image]

and

[image]

I hope anyone here can help me.

Comment: It has something to do with your repository's, try troubleshooting: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure

Comment: bain's duplicate question should have a answer - note you will need to do it for `i386` not `amd64`

Answer (score 1):

Open a Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Then Copy and Paste this command in prompt and press Enter:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com A902DDA375E52366
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```